# Unable to capture screenshot in Chrome Headless mode while switched in new tab

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I have below Configuration :

> Selenium  3.8.0
>
> Java 8
>
> Chrome Browser 60
>
> Chromedriver v 2.31 64bit

I'm running my test in chrome headless mode. The issues is, the browser get unresponsive while it switch to new tab and try to capture the snap.

Following Error recorded :

> [727.930][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
>
> [727.934][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying

The code where it causing the issue :

```
if(myprofile.postalAddress.size()>0)
{
     
    myprofile.getGetAddressMapIcon().get(0).click();
    LogWriter.logger.info("Address Clicked");
    CommonMethods.switchWindow(driver);
    TakeScreenshot.passedScreenShot("GoogleMap");
    driver.close();
    CommonMethods.switchToParentWindow(driver);
    LogWriter.logger.info("Map Window closed");
}
```

`SwitchWindow` Method :

```
public static void switchWindow(WebDriver driver) throws IOException
{
    
    parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) 
    {

        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        LogWriter.logger.info("-----");
    }
    LogWriter.logger.info("Window Title : " + driver.getTitle());
}
```

`TakeScreenshot` Method :

```
public static void passedScreenShot(String testname) throws IOException
{
    File sourceFile = ((TakesScreenshot) DriverSetup.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMM_yyyy__hh_mm_ssaa");
    destDir = System.getProperty("user.home")+"/AutomationTemp/Reports/Screenshots/PassedTest";
    new File(destDir).mkdirs();
     
    String destFile = dateFormat.format(new Date())+"RCON" + "_" + testname +".png";

    try 
    {
        Files.copy(sourceFile, new File(destDir + "/" + destFile));
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

While I'm running the same in GUI mode then all all works fine. Can someone help what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is within your **switchWindow(WebDriver driver)** function as follows :

Within **switchWindow(WebDriver driver)** you are trying to `switchTo().window(winHandle)` without validating the **`winHandle`** as follows :

```
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) 
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
```

Here you are not validating whether **`winHandle`** have picked up **`parentWindow`** or `windowHandle` of **`child window`**.

### Solution :

So the solution will be to validate that the **`winHandle`** must not be the **`parentWindow`** as follows:

```
public static void switchWindow(WebDriver driver) throws IOException
{
    parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) 
    {
    if (!parentWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(winHandle))
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        //you can do anything on the new tab/window
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. After replacing your code still no success. The same test running in GUI mode fine but glitch is only in headless mode.

Comment: I guess that was chromedriver issue. I have updated chrome 63 and chromedriver 2.34. Now its working fine. +1 for your code suggestion